# How do I find the center of a circle while only seeing outer edge?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Using matlab, I need to programmatically find the center of a circle while I'm only able to see the outer edge of the circle.

Below is a test image I am trying to process:

Ignore the black around the outer edge. I have my camera behind a scope, that is why you can only see a small magnified circle in the middle. These black circles are actually a target, so there are multiple rings nested inside each other. 
[image: Image to process]

### Script using imfindcircles()

In the matlab script below, I used imfindcircles(). There are two problems with imfindcircles().
 1. It takes about 2-3 seconds per call, which is to slow for my application.
 2. It cannot predict the center of the circle in my example image above. It needs to see more of the circle first.

```
Rmin = 40; %7 and 12 for small circle
Rmax = 100;

% Create video input object.
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1);

% Set video input object properties for this application.
% Note that example uses both SET method and dot notation method.
set(vid,'TriggerRepeat',100);
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 5;


vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_1280x720');
%src = getselectedsource(vid);

%number of frames to get each time the camera is triggered
vid.FramesPerTrigger = 1;

%return grayscale for one less thing to process
vid.ReturnedColorspace = 'grayscale';

%make the trigger type manual. This allows use to grab one frame at a time
triggerconfig(vid, 'manual');

% allow us to capture unlimited frames, with only starting the video once
vid.TriggerRepeat = Inf;

%preview(vid);

%start(vid);

%trigger(vid);

%stoppreview(vid);

% Create a figure window.
%figure;

% Start acquiring frames.
start(vid);

while(true)

    trigger(vid);

    %get a single image frame
    image = getdata(vid);

    %draw the image on screen
    imshow(image);
    drawnow;     % update figure window

    %set the center of the image. This is used as an additional way to
    %calibrate the score, camera, and laser. You can change where the "center" of
    %the camera image is by adjusting these values.
    % [x, y]
    imageCenter = [500, 500];
    viscircles(imageCenter, 5,'EdgeColor','r');

    %find circles (the target) in the image and draw a circle around it
    [centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(image,[Rmin Rmax], 'ObjectPolarity', 'dark');

    %make sure a circle on screen was found
    if(centers)
        %draw circle found on screen
        viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','b');

        %calculate distance from center of the image and the center of the circle
        %x minus x; y minus y; then calc hypotenuse
        circleCenterX = centers(1,1);
        circleCenterY = centers(1,2);

        imageCenterX = imageCenter(1,1);
        imageCenterY = imageCenter(1,2);

        %calculate the di
        distanceX = circleCenterX - imageCenterX;  
        distanceY = circleCenterY - imageCenterY ;

        %calculate the hypotenuse (b^2 + b^2 = c^2)
        hypotenuse = sqrt(distanceX^2 + distanceY^2);

        %create sound based on distance from the center of the image
        a=sin(2*pi*hypotenuse*(0:0.000125:0.05));
        sound(a);

        disp(hypotenuse);

        %if you are withing X pixel of the center make a beeping noise
        if(hypotenuse <= 15)
            a=sin(2*pi*400*(0:0.000125:0.05));
            sound(a);
            sound(a);
            sound(a);
        end

        %show a measuring line to verfiy results
        %h = imdistline;
    end

    %clear memory after each frame to avoid memory leak
    flushdata(vid, 'triggers');

end

%doesnät get run but use these commands to clean up before running the
%script again
imaqreset();
%stop(vid);
%delete(vid);
%clear;
%close(gcf);
```

### Script trying to replace imfindcircles()

To speed up the processing, I threw our imfindcircles() and am trying to create my own function to do something similar. The script converts the image to a binary image, then uses regionprops to find the center of the white objects. You will also notice a rudimentary ideas for detecting the center in the code. It also tries to find the center on the idea that when two or more perfect circles are placed inside each other, they will all have the same center... but in my picture example above, this simple concept fails to work because it cannot even detect a single circle, let alone the other circles inside of it.

```
function circleCenter = findCircleCenter(image, drawOnImage, toGray)
    %in order to find the center, find the center of all objects in an image.
    %Once we have the centers, we find the shortest distance between these
    %objects. Our image has multiple circle, each inside the other. The center
    %of all these cirlces are the same. By finding the shortest distance
    %between the objects, we can safely assume we found the center of our
    %target when we find two points are very close to each other. 

    %Adjust the number of pixels between the two points of the circle.
    %Explained in details above.
    minCenterPixelDist = 8;
    %the minimum amount of pixels needed in a region to be considered an
    %object for measurement
    minPixelArea = 100;

    if(toGray == 1)
        %convert to grayscale
        image = rgb2gray(image);
        %figure, imshow(image);
    end

    %find the two closest points
    %see if they are less than 8 pixels apart, this is the center

    %threshold the image to make a binary image
    BW = image > 100; %100
    %figure, imshow(BW);

    %http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imdilate.html
    %se = strel('line',11,90);
    %I2 = imdilate(BW,se);
    %imshow(BW), title('Original')
    %figure, imshow(I2), title('Dilated')

    originalBW = BW;  
    se = strel('disk',2);        
    erodedBW = imerode(originalBW,se);
    %imshow(originalBW), figure, imshow(erodedBW)

    %find regions in binary image
    regionImage = erodedBW;
    s = regionprops(regionImage, image, {'Centroid','WeightedCentroid','Area','FilledImage'});

    %draw the regions found on screen.
    if(drawOnImage == 1)
        %figure, imshow(regionImage);
        title('Weighted (red) and Unweighted (blue) Centroid Locations');
        hold on
        numObj = numel(s);
        for k = 1 : numObj

            %only display regions that are bigger than X number of pixels
            if(s(k).Area > minPixelArea)
                plot(s(k).WeightedCentroid(1), s(k).WeightedCentroid(2), 'r*');
                plot(s(k).Centroid(1), s(k).Centroid(2), 'bo');
                text(s(k).Centroid(1),s(k).Centroid(2), sprintf('%2.1f', s(k).Centroid(1)), 'EdgeColor','b','Color','r');
            end
        end
        hold off
    end

    shortestDist = 100; %stores the current shortest distance found, default to somethign massive so it gets overwriten easily
    shortestDistIndex = 0;%stores the index of the point with the shortest distance

    for idx = 1:numel(s)

        %make sure the current element has more than X number of pixels
        %before processing it
        if(s(idx).Area > minPixelArea)
            %get the x and y of the current element
            currentX = s(idx).Centroid(1);
            currentY = s(idx).Centroid(1);

            %get the x and y of the next element
            try
                nextX = s(idx + 1).Centroid(1);
                nextY = s(idx + 1).Centroid(1);
            catch
                %if we are on the last element, the try statement will fail, and
                %this will end the for loop
                break;
            end

            %calculate the distance between the current centroid and the next one
            distanceX = nextX - currentX;  
            distanceY = nextY - currentY;

            %calculate the hypotenuse (b^2 + b^2 = c^2)
            hypotenuse = sqrt(distanceX^2 + distanceY^2);

            %if the distance is less than the current "shortest distance",
            %overwrite the variable
            if(hypotenuse <= shortestDist)
                shortestDist = hypotenuse;
                shortestDistIndex = idx;
            end
        end
    end

    %if the closest points are within a certain number of pixels, we can
    %assume the are the centers of two circles 
    %also make sure the area of this shortest distance is greater than
    %minPixel area
    if(shortestDist < minCenterPixelDist)
         %get the x and y of our shortest distance centroids
         centerOneX = s(shortestDistIndex).Centroid(1);
         centerOneY = s(shortestDistIndex).Centroid(2);

         centerTwoX = s(shortestDistIndex + 1).Centroid(1);
         centerTwoY = s(shortestDistIndex + 1).Centroid(2);

         %calculate the average between the two closest points
         circleCenterX = (centerOneX + centerTwoX)/2;
         circleCenterY = (centerOneY + centerTwoY)/2;

         circleCenter = [circleCenterX, circleCenterY];

         disp(circleCenter);
    else
        circleCenter = [];
    end
end
```

Comment: Maybe if you showed the code where you process the image and use `imfindcircles` someone might be able to show you how to get it to work.

Comment: maybe downsample the frame to a more manageable size before calling imfindcircles?

Comment: To be clear you're actually to find the center of the circles that are partially viewable through the microscope image, not the center of the big image image circle (the entire field of view)? Despite your wording, I don't think this is perfectly clear.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to predict the center of the circle as seen through the scope. Also, I have figured out how to do it. I will be posting the solution within the next couple days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My Solution

I have written a short tutorial about how I solved the problem and posted all my code to github. [See the tutorial and code.](https://github.com/zechdc/matlab_circle_center) The tutorial was written in the projects README.md file so it should appear when you view the github page and scroll down a bit. [I used the math @vadim123 suggested here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/574832/43774)

Answer (score 1):

You could try Hough Transform for circles detection. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_detection_process)

Comment: `imfindcircles` is based on the Hough transform.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute it if you have 3 points (A, B, C) on the circle. The center of the *circumscribed circle* can be found at the intersection of any two perpendicular bisectors on the AB, AC or BC segments. For more details, take a look at [circumscribed circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) article on Wikipedia.

Comment: If you have more than one point, [least squares fitting techniques](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15060-fitcircle-m) can be used.